# jQuery: Conflict with removeData() executing at inadequate times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a modal window used to update or add a new object `Store`.

This modal is called remotely which information is loaded from a GET method constructed in ASP.NET.

**Button that calls the modal:**

```
<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" 
         data-target="#modal-action-store" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  NEW STORE
        </a>
</div>
```

**Html of the modal:**

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
@using Application.Models

<form asp-action="Create" role="form">    
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader
    { Heading = String.Format("Actualización de Modelo: Tiendas") })

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            {... more elements}
       </div>
</form>
```

**GET Method:**

```
    public IActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        List<Department> DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
        DepartmentList = (from department in _context.Departments
                          select department).ToList();
        DepartmentList.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0, DepartmentName = "-- Seleccione Departamento --" });
        ViewBag.ListofDepartment = DepartmentList;

        StoreIndexData edit = new StoreIndexData();
        List<District> ListofDistrict = new List<District>();
        ListofDistrict.Insert(0, new District { DistrictID = 0, DistrictName = "-- PRUEBA --" });
        ViewBag.ListofDistrict = ListofDistrict;

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Stores/_Create.cshtml");
    }
```

**The problem:**

I have the following jQuery which asigns a value to `DistrictID` once the modal opens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var wasclicked = 0;
    var $this = this;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            //is AddNew Store button is hitted, this var = 1
            wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            //global.wasclicked = 0;
            wasclicked = 0;
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            console.log($('#DistrictID').length);
            //if wasclicked equals 1 that means we are in the AddNew Store scenario.
            if (wasclicked == 1) {
                //a default value is sent to District dropdownlist
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem right now is that after this line jQuery is executed, the value that was assigned to `DistrictID` gets overwritten by :

```
  ViewBag.ListofDistrict = ListofDistrict; //"-- PRUEBA --"
```

And this line is lost:

```
var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
```

What I suspect is that the information coming from the Controller overwrites any result from jQuery over the  in the modal.

After debugging I have identified three diferent moments:

**Moment 1: First time we open the modal**

[image]

- The modal hasn't opened yet and the jQuery executes
- For this reason it does not identify `DistrictID`
- The result from the GET Action fills the modal's inputs.

**Moment 2 - Part 1: Second time we open the modal**

[image]

- This time the modal opens before the jQuery is executed
- The `DistrictID` has the value from the GET Method before we assign the value from jQuery

**Moment 2 - Part 2: When the value from jQuery is assigned**

[image]

- The value from jQuery is assigned to `DistrictID`
- This value will be overwritten by the result of the GET Action

**Question:**

Can anyone explain or help me understand what might be causing this? What else can I do to identify the reason behind this?

Comment: Could you possibly add the relevant HTML as well please? That way, we can reproduce the issue

Comment: @user184994 sure thing! information added!

Comment: When you click to open the Modal, the element `#DepartmentID` doesn't exists in the View right?

Comment: At this moment none of them exists by the time the code is executed when the modal is called, that's why I believe the best way was to pre-load the info so the code won't face an undefined exception. In adition, if we are in the case of using the modal to add a new `Store` these fields will come with zero information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying moving the assigning of html to `districtID` from your main view to the `document.ready` of modal popUp view.

```
    @model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
    @using Application.Models

    <form asp-action="Create" role="form">    
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader
        { Heading = String.Format("Actualización de Modelo: Tiendas") })

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {... more elements}
           </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
            //if wasclicked equals 1 that means we are in the AddNew Store scenario.
            if (wasclicked == 1) {
                //a default value is sent to District dropdownlist
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
    });

</script>
```

PS: Default option can be also be used. refer the below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))">
     <option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`modal()` only accepts an options object or a string. To append elements to your modal, we can append them when the `show.bs.modal` is triggered:

```js
$('#modal-action-store').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
 var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
    $('#DistrictID').html(items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" 
         data-target="#modal-action-store" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  NEW STORE
        </a>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="modal-action-store">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Josan, However I'm not able to replicate this on the project. I've deployed an online version for this: http://plataformafantasypark.azurewebsites.net/   User: adelgado Password: $Adelgado33 Under the menu 'Tiendas'. I duplicated the code to test if $(document).ready(function ()) had any effect on the code. Hope you can take a look at it

Comment: Updated the online version. When 'NuevaTienda' is hitted,DistrictID field get the value that is intended but then it goes blank, God knows why..

Comment: @Luis you probably have another piece of code that is removing the value from the element

Comment: You can see the `-- Seleccione Distrito --` and it blinks and is removed. So there is something in your js, clearing your element. Like Josan said

Comment: I've just deleted this script from the online version: <script src="~/js/store-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script> and now it's not deleting. I'll post the complete code of that js file. It's purpose it's to clear the data once the modal closes so, in case you choose another ´Store´ to edit for example, the previous data don't stick around.

Comment: Updated. Just as mentioned, if a `Store` is clicked to see it's details it works ok, but if another one is picked to see it's details too, without that file, the data from the first one sticks around.

Comment: Update: I've tried to integrate the content of that js file with what I have in the Index view. It seems I can't possibly join this functionalities. The values on DistrictID gets killed (I believe by `$(this).removeData('bs.modal'));` even tho that event is called after the modal closes and `('#DepartmentID').change(function ())` dont execute/go thru

Comment: Can you post all of the code that has to do with the modal

Answer (score 0):

I would update your `http://plataformafantasypark.azurewebsites.net/Stores/create` to contain `<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>` by default. This would limit the options to overwrite the element with zero entries.
This would make your js code easier too.

By the way, why do you use `document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick`  when you can use `$("#modalbutton").on("click", function(){});` because you are using jQuery for everything else.