# jQuery result beign overwritten by the info sent from the GET Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a modal window used to update or add a new object `Store`.

This modal is called remotely which information is loaded from a GET method constructed in ASP.NET.

**Button that calls the modal:**

```
<div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
    <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" 
         data-target="#modal-action-store" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  NEW STORE
        </a>
</div>
```

**Html of the modal:**

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
@using Application.Models

<form asp-action="Create" role="form">    
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader
    { Heading = String.Format("Actualización de Modelo: Tiendas") })

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            {... more elements}
       </div>
</form>
```

**GET Method:**

```
    public IActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        List<Department> DepartmentList = new List<Department>();
        DepartmentList = (from department in _context.Departments
                          select department).ToList();
        DepartmentList.Insert(0, new Department { DepartmentID = 0, DepartmentName = "-- Seleccione Departamento --" });
        ViewBag.ListofDepartment = DepartmentList;

        StoreIndexData edit = new StoreIndexData();
        List<District> ListofDistrict = new List<District>();
        ListofDistrict.Insert(0, new District { DistrictID = 0, DistrictName = "-- PRUEBA --" });
        ViewBag.ListofDistrict = ListofDistrict;

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Stores/_Create.cshtml");
    }
```

**The problem:**

I have the following jQuery which asigns a value to `DistrictID` once the modal opens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var wasclicked = 0;
    var $this = this;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            //is AddNew Store button is hitted, this var = 1
            wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-store').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            //global.wasclicked = 0;
            wasclicked = 0;
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });

        $('#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            console.log($('#DistrictID').length);
            //if wasclicked equals 1 that means we are in the AddNew Store scenario.
            if (wasclicked == 1) {
                //a default value is sent to District dropdownlist
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem right now is that after this line jQuery is executed, the value that was assigned to `DistrictID` gets overwritten by :

```
  ViewBag.ListofDistrict = ListofDistrict; //"-- PRUEBA --"
```

And this line is lost:

```
var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
```

What I suspect is that the information coming from the Controller overwrites any result from jQuery over the  in the modal.

After debugging I have identified three diferent moments:

**Moment 1: First time we open the modal**

[image]

- The modal hasn't opened yet and the jQuery executes
- For this reason it does not identify `DistrictID`
- The result from the GET Action fills the modal's inputs.

**Moment 2 - Part 1: Second time we open the modal**

[image]

- This time the modal opens before the jQuery is executed
- The `DistrictID` has the value from the GET Method before we assign the value from jQuery

**Moment 2 - Part 2: When the value from jQuery is assigned**

[image]

- The value from jQuery is assigned to `DistrictID`
- This value will be overwritten by the result of the GET Action

**Question:**

Can anyone explain or help me understand what might be causing this? What else can I do to identify the reason behind this?

Comment: Sure, where is your AJAX function?

Comment: How did you accomplish it for department dropdown? you can use the same concept right?

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas Department dropdown gets it information from the GET Controller while the District dropdown is sent as ViewBag.ListofDistrict = string.Empty; to the view and gets its data from the jQuery. This is the scenario where the modal is used to add a new Store. If its an scenario of an Update, District will get it's value depending on the Department that Store has, but I'm not showing that info because it's not part of the problme

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas the problem is a little bigger thant that. I thank you for the suggestions to workaround this particular issue but if I don't identify why this is happening I won't be able to fix the next problems (since none of the following jQuery I'm not showing in this question is working properly).

Comment: @Magnus After going thru the project I've seen that there is no AJAX per se, I'll edit the question. Although this issue remains as the result of jQuery being overwritten by the information coming from the GET Action since the information coming from the controller is what come last.

Comment: Trying moving the assigning of html to `districtID` from your main view to the `document.ready` of modal popUp view.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas take that code out of '#modal-action-store').on('shown.bs.modal' ?

Comment: Comment that entire block of code and move it to your modal PopUp partialView.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your code:

```
var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
$('#DistrictID').html(items);
```

by

```
var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
var currentItems = $('#DistrictID').html();
$('#DistrictID').html(items + currentItems)
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying moving the assigning of html to `districtID` from your main view to the `document.ready` of modal popUp view.

```
    @model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.StoreIndexData
    @using Application.Models

    <form asp-action="Create" role="form">    
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader
        { Heading = String.Format("Actualización de Modelo: Tiendas") })

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DepartmentID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select asp-for="DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDepartment,"DepartmentID","DepartmentName"))"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {... more elements}
           </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
            //if wasclicked equals 1 that means we are in the AddNew Store scenario.
            if (wasclicked == 1) {
                //a default value is sent to District dropdownlist
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>";
                $('#DistrictID').html(items);
            }
    });

</script>
```

PS: Default option can be also be used. refer the below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Distrito</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="DistrictID" name="DistrictID" asp-for="DistrictID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofDistrict,"DistrictID","DistrictName"))">
     <option value='0'>-- Seleccione Distrito --</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this approach is that `DistrictID` exists only when the modal opens, not when the document is ready, for this reason if I take it out of the shown.bs.modal it will never executes past the if() since no `DistrictID` exists yet.

Comment: Please note that, `document.ready` you see in the above code is with respect to your partialView(Modal PopUp View), not your main view.

Comment: It worked fine! I will test it on other scripts justo to be sure it applies to most of the situations, will come back to mark your answer as the main answer for the question in a few hours (2:30am here). Thanks.

Comment: Kumar, your answer helped me to get past these problems. I had a question with a bounty on it. If you want feel free to leave an answer (can be the same as here) and I'll accept it (and then delete this question to avoid repetition). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609994/jquery-conflict-with-removedata-executing-at-inadequate-times

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo I'm glad it helped. Sure will post the answer there, so that we can avoid repetitions.